# Javascript: Split array of arrays into multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, firebase, flot

serious problem here, I have an array like this:

```
[[0,50],[0,68],[1,26],[2,9],[2,32]]
```

The form I need is to split this array into two separated arrays like this:

```
array1 = [[0,50][1,0][2,9]]
array2 = [[0,68][1,26][2,32]]
```

Yeah you are right guys, I need that to build flot chart.

If anybody interested in source of data this is how it looks in firebase:

```
{
  "1433203200000" : {
    "-JpgJnANTpQFprRieImv" : {
      "events" : 5,
      "name" : "Home office",
      "returningVisitors" : 9,
      "totalVisitors" : 50
    },
    "-JqsQjFTjHpzKqWgE_KJ" : {
      "events" : 10,
      "name" : "Samin Place",
      "returningVisitors" : 32,
      "totalVisitors" : 68
    }
  },
  "1433289600000" : {
    "-JqsQjFTjHpzKqWgE_KJ" : {
      "name" : "Samin Place",
      "newVisitors" : 1,
      "returningVisitors" : 25,
      "totalVisitors" : 26
    }
  },
  "1433376000000" : {
    "-JpgJnANTpQFprRieImv" : {
      "events" : 5,
      "name" : "Home office",
      "returningVisitors" : 9,
      "totalVisitors" : 9
    },
    "-JqsQjFTjHpzKqWgE_KJ" : {
      "events" : 10,
      "name" : "Samin Place",
      "returningVisitors" : 32,
      "totalVisitors" : 32
    }
  }
}
```

The point is loop each timestamp and each child, there we have totalVisitors that's the value I need for my chart.

**BONUS**

As you can see first timestamp have two childs thats fine, but second timestamp have only one child - "-JqsQjFTjHpzKqWgE_KJ" so I need to add null value for missing one into new array (in our example it's array1 second position).

That's what I'm calling **CHALLENGE** :)

Any help is very appreciated, thanks for attention.

Edit:

maybe if it can help to someone this is chart which I need

[here is link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRaHS.jpg)

X-axis - are timestamps
Y-axis - totalVisitors value
Lines - every unique timestamp child

Comment: From where `[1,0]` comes?

Comment: That's the challenge :), you can see firebase data source with three timestamps, first and last have two childs but the middle one just one...so I need to create this [1,0] as value for missing one. Have no idea if it is possible or not :)

Comment: Do you have always maximum two childs? More precisely, what is the maximum?

Comment: It seams you have simply to: 
- loop through the array
- add the first element to the first array
- add the second to the second array
- if an element is missing add the "null" replacement

Comment: @АнатолийИвашов it's not always two it can be always variable for every timestamp.

Comment: @pinturic Yeah that's nice idea but ehm...how? :D

Comment: Do you have so many arrays (array1, array2), how many different `-J...`-like keys? I mean, in your code you have two different keys: `"-JpgJnANTpQFprRieImv"` and `"-JqsQjFTjHpzKqWgE_KJ"` that's why you have two arrays - `array1` and `array2`, am I write?

Comment: @АнатолийИвашов yeah exactly, every array is dataset for chart. So every dataset will create a line for my chart with values of array. So if there will be a timestamp with three childs for example I would need three arrays.

Comment: It's not easy. If you give some time, maybe i will help you)

Comment: @АнатолийИвашов Yeah I know it's not easy I'm waiting for blessing me from yesterday but it still didn't come. If you find solution, you'll be my hero :)

Comment: I added an answer, look please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created jsfiddle for you. Please tell, is it what you need?

http://jsfiddle.net/1vdryy3L/1/

```
// first, we'll get all possible keys ('key' is e.g. "-JpgJnANTpQFprRieImv")
var keys = [];
for (var i in data) {
    for (var j in data[i]) {
        if (keys.indexOf(j) == -1) {
            keys.push(j);
        }        
    }
}

var result = {}, tmp, k;
for (i in keys) {
    tmp = []; k = 0;
    for (var j in data) {
        if (data[j][keys[i]]) {
            tmp.push([k, data[j][keys[i]].totalVisitors]);
        } else {
            tmp.push([k, 0]);
        }
        k++;
    }
    result['array' + i] = tmp;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work provided that you are using jQuery. If you are not simply replace the jquery statements with standard js ones. (I have prepared a jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcjrb5mz/1):

```
var first = []
var second = [];
var my_data = {
  "1433203200000" : {
    "-JpgJnANTpQFprRieImv" : {
      "events" : 5,
      "name" : "Home office",
      "returningVisitors" : 9,
      "totalVisitors" : 50
    },
    "-JqsQjFTjHpzKqWgE_KJ" : {
      "events" : 10,
      "name" : "Samin Place",
      "returningVisitors" : 32,
      "totalVisitors" : 68
    }
  },
  "1433289600000" : {
    "-JqsQjFTjHpzKqWgE_KJ" : {
      "name" : "Samin Place",
      "newVisitors" : 1,
      "returningVisitors" : 25,
      "totalVisitors" : 26
    }
  },
  "1433376000000" : {
    "-JpgJnANTpQFprRieImv" : {
      "events" : 5,
      "name" : "Home office",
      "returningVisitors" : 9,
      "totalVisitors" : 9
    },
    "-JqsQjFTjHpzKqWgE_KJ" : {
      "events" : 10,
      "name" : "Samin Place",
      "returningVisitors" : 32,
      "totalVisitors" : 32
    }
  }
} 
var count = 0;
$.each(my_data, function(key, value){
    if (value["-JpgJnANTpQFprRieImv"]){
        first.push([count, value["-JpgJnANTpQFprRieImv"]["totalVisitors"]])
    } else {
        first.push([count, 0])
    }
    if (value["-JqsQjFTjHpzKqWgE_KJ"]){
        second.push([count, value["-JqsQjFTjHpzKqWgE_KJ"]["totalVisitors"]])
    } else {
        second.push([count, 0])
    }
    count++;
});
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention about that I'm using AngularJS, anyway that seems like it can help me to make it work after few changes as I need to loop all "timestamp" childs not only two as there can be variable number of childs with variable id's. Many thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I will when my reputation increase little bit :)